# Number of prime numbers in a given range

Tags: java, primes

I've written a method that should return the numbers of prime numbers in a given range:

```
public static int numberOfPrim(int up){                 // Returns amount of primnumbers from 0 to up
    if(up<=0){
        return 0;
    }
    int primAmount = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i<=up ; i++){
        if(checkIfPrim(i) == true){
           primAmount++;
        }
    }
    return primAmount;
}

public static boolean checkIfPrim(int number){         // If number is prim -> return true
    if (number < 2){
        return false;
    }
    boolean prim = true;
    if(number == 2){
        return prim;
    }
    boolean[] con = new boolean[number];
    for(int i = 2; i < number; i++){
        if(number %i == 0) {
            con[i] = true;
        }
    }
    for(int j = 0; j < number; j++){
        if(con[j] == true){
            prim = false;
        }
    }
    return prim;
}
```

The code is working like I want it to. For example, `numberOfPrim(10)` should return `4` (2, 3, 5, 7). I'm just asking if there are any locations where I can improve my code, like shorten it or if there are any other possibilities to write such a method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. What is the purpose of shortening the term "Prime(s)" to Prim in your method names? IMO `numberOfPrimes` and `checkIfPrime` are more readable. The same is true for `primAmount` etc.
2. `if(checkIfPrim(i) == true)` can simply be `if (checkIfPrim(i))`
3. Your spacing is inconsistent. Generally, it is recommended to leave a space between a control structure (`for`, `if`, `while` etc.) and its following open paren, which you adhere to exactly once in `checkIfPrim`, but not elsewhere. The same applies to operators: Write `up <= 0` instead of `up<=0`.
4. Your `checkIfPrim` method is grossly overcomplicated. First of all, you check every number up to `number` for divisibility, while it should be obvious that there can be no divisor greater than `number / 2`. Still, if you think about the problem, you will soon arrive at another conclusion, which is that you only need to check numbers up to `sqrt(number)`, because you can write `a * b = number` (with `a` and `b` being positive integers), which is to say that `a` and `b` are *divisors* of `number`. Now, letting `sqrt(number) = c * c`, and by thinking about how multiplication behaves, we can conclude that either `a` or `b` must always be lesser or equal to  while the other must be greater or equal to `c`, because when either `a` or `b` is smaller than `c` the total product would shrink unless the other one grows to counteract this fact.
   The next problem is your use of a `boolean` array, which is completely redundant. You do not need to store the result of the division test for each number separately, but you only have to keep track of whether you have found a divisor for `number` (=> `number` is not prime) or not (=> `number` is prime). All in all, I would rewrite the method to something like this:

   ```
   public static boolean checkIfPrime(int number) {
       if (number < 2) {
           return false;
       }

       if (number == 2) {
           return true;
       }

       int root = (int) Math.sqrt(number);
       for (int i = 2; i <= root; i++) {
           if (number % i == 0) {
               return false;
           }
       }

       return true;
   }
   ```

---

Although this code should be reasonably efficient for relatively small numbers, there are faster algorithms to solve this problem. However, most of these are not as easy to implement, and if you are not planning on doing this for very large integers, then you should be fine with the changes I suggested. If you are still interested in improving effiency, I point you to the [Wikipedia article about the prime-counting function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function) for a start.

Comment: "Generally, it is recommended to leave a space between a control structure (for, if, while etc.) and its following open paren" Highly subjective, but I agree that there should be consistency.  If OP is new to Java, they should take the time to find a format that's aesthetically pleasing to them.

Comment: 1. Well I'm from Germany where we call those prime numbers "Primzahlen" 2. That should be obvious to me.. thank you 3. I copy/paste the code, in the IDE it looked ok.. 4.That sounds good, I will test it . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Consider

```
// If number is prime -> return true
public static boolean isPrime(int number) {
    if (number == 2) {
        return true;
    }

    if (number < 2 || number % 2 == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 3, n = 1 + (int)Math.sqrt(number); i <= n; i += 2) {
        if (number % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Putting comments on separate lines makes it easier to see that they exist when quickly scanning the code.  And in this case, it avoids unnecessary scrolling.

Boolean methods in Java are normally named `isSomething` or `hasSomething`.

The only even prime is 2.  If we eliminate that first, then we can check for numbers less than 2 or divisible by 2 at the same time.

We don't need the `prim` variable, as we can `return false` as soon as we find a reason.  If we get to the end, we can `return true`.  This has the same effect as your code with less scaffolding.

Since we've already checked for even numbers, we only need to check odd numbers in the `for` loop.

If you can multiply two factors to get a product, at least one of the factors must be less than or equal to the square root of the number.  You can see this by trying to multiply two numbers greater than the square root together.  If everything is positive, the product will be greater than the target number.  So once we've checked the square root, we don't need to keep going.  If there was a pair, we'd already have found half of it.

We could tweak the `isPrime` method a little more and likely make it a little faster.  However, we have other options that don't require `isPrime` at all.

#### Sieve of Eratosthenes

If you know the maximum number that you have to check and need to check many numbers, consider using the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) or similar.  That's the most efficient way to find all the primes in a range.  So you'd first find all the primes and then just query a data structure thereafter.

There are a number of [implementations](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sieve-of-eratosthenes+java) on this site.

In this case, you could have a method `countPrimesUnder` that would iterate over the data structure and count the primes.

Comment: This is just my opinion, but wouldn't it be easier to just have two return statements, which both return `prim`? That would avoid unnecessary code, and be a bit less confusing

Comment: There are implementations of more efficient sieves as well, although not as many. Maybe I should post my Bernstein-Atkin sieve. However, as Ben's answer hints with its reference to Wikipedia, it's even faster not to compute the primes at all.